# Search using wildcard character in Bootstrap-table

Tags: bootstrap-table

Is it possible in `Bootstrap-table` to search in the table, using the wildcard character * ?

For example, in this [table](http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/2106/) I want to search the word `*blog*` in order to filter the records which contain the word blog.